# Is there any free way to write on a PDF form?

Tags: windows, pdf, editing

I have been sent a form as a scanned PDF (it has no fields). There are several online tools that can be used to fill it in such as FillAnyPDF.com, but these do not suit my needs. They either watermark the output or straight up charge you to download the result (note: they don't tell you this until *after* you've filled in your form, beware!).

Is there any free alternative? I'm playing around with Foxit but can't find the functionality I need (add text, images, save as new PDF).

Comment: Do you need to save it as PDF again? I assume you're on Windows?

Comment: Yes (to email), and yes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free PDF Editor for Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/5989/free-pdf-editor-for-windows) and/or [Smallest free PDF form filler?](http://superuser.com/questions/34571/smallest-free-pdf-form-filler)

Answer (score 1):

I found an excellent service: [PDF Escape](http://www.pdfescape.com) which provides the same and better services as FillAnyPDF.com and PDFFiller Inc., but free and no registration required.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past to edit PDF files: http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfedit/

Answer (score 0):

Libreoffice supports editing PDF Files and reexporting them. 
[Link](http://www.libreoffice.org/)

(as well as all the other office stuff.)